# What does "Stuck out of " mean?

Tags: word-usage

A red silk bookmark *stuck out of* many of the books.

In this sentence above, what does "stuck out of "mean?

Comment: Definition of _stick out_ - https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stick-out

Answer (score 2):

Many of the books have bookmarks in them indicating where the reader had got to when reading them – these bookmarks are made of red silk and protrude beyond the book itself to indicate where they are.

See an example: https://s3.amazonaws.com/libapps/accounts/11428/images/Book-Bookmark.jpg